# ¿Por qué este código tan simple y aparentemente correcto, da error de compilación?

Tags: java, variables, conversión-de-tipos

```
class PromocionAutomaticaError {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte b = 50;
        b = b * 2; // Esta línea arroja error en la compilacion
    }
}
```

Ésta es la línea que arroja el error a la hora de la compilación.

```
b = b * 2;
```

.. la cual está intentado almacenar **50 * 2**, un valor de byte perfectamente válido.

---

**Adjunto error..**

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
>
> ```
>    b = b * 2; // Error! Cannot assign an int to a byte!
> ```

Comment: Me parece que no puedes multiplicar byte * int.

Comment: El lenguaje Java requiere que uses una conversión `(byte)` cuando asignes una expresión de valor `int`  a un byte como es tu caso. Esto se resuelve del siguiente modo: **`b =  (byte) (b * 2);`**

Comment: Buen comentario. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Motivo del error

Como indica el error que estás teniendo:

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Lo que ocurre aquí es **una conversión de `int` a `byte`**.

En la especificación existe lo que se llama *conversión primitiva de estrechamiento*, y que es explicada en el apartado [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

La especificación, en el mismo enlace dice lo siguiente:

> Una conversión primitiva de estrechamiento puede perder información
>   sobre la magnitud global de un valor numérico y también puede perder
>   precisión y rango.

Es lo que ocurriría precisamente aquí si la conversión se hiciera porque un [`byte` es de menor tamaño que un `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).

En el apartado [5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) de la especificación, viene indicado lo siguiente, ente otras cosas:

> ... Assignment contexts allow the value of an expression to be
>   assigned (§15.26) to a variable; the type of the expression must be
>   converted to the type of the variable.
>
> ... In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28)
>   of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> ---
>
> ... Los contextos de asignación permiten que el valor de una expresión
>   se asigne (§15.26) a una variable; **el tipo de expresión debe
>   convertirse al tipo de la variable**.
>
> ... Además, si la expresión es una **expresión constante** (§15.28) de
>   tipo `byte`, `short`, `char` o `int`:
>
> **Se puede usar una conversión primitiva de estrechamiento si el tipo de
>   la variable es `byte`, `short` o `char`, y el valor de la expresión
>   constante se puede representar en el tipo de la variable.**

O sea, la especificación manda que *el tipo de la expresión sea convertido al tipo de la variable* (conversión explícita), salvo el caso especial en el que se aplicaría una *conversión primitiva de estrechamiento* (conversión implícita). no se cumple aquí, porque el valor de la *expresión constante*, que es `2` no es ni `byte`, ni `short`, ni `char`.

Veámoslo con algunos ejemplos:

```
    /*Operador*/
    final byte b=50;

    /*Operandos*/ 
    final byte    bOperand=2;
    final short   sOperand=2;
    final char    cOperand=2;
    final int     iOperand=2;
    final double  dOperand=2;
    final long    lOperand=2;
    final float   fOperand=2;

    byte bMult=0;

    /* Casos correctos */
    bMult = b * bOperand; 
    bMult = b * sOperand; 
    bMult = b * iOperand; 
    bMult = b * cOperand; 

    /* Casos erróneos */

    bMult = b * dOperand; //Error, no se cumple el caso especial
    bMult = b * lOperand; //Error, no se cumple el caso especial
    bMult = b * fOperand; //Error, no se cumple el caso especial
```

Ahora me dirás, ¿por qué la línea `bMult = b * iOperand;` funciona, si es casi similar a mi código?

Por lo mismo que comentaba antes de las asignación *implícita* y *explícita*. Hay una pequeña diferencia y no sé si lo habrás notado: las variables que intervienen en la multiplicación son declaradas `final`. Si a cualquiera de ellas le quitas la palabra `final` el código daría error, porque el compilador no aceptaría entrar un un terreno desconocido. Ahora mismo, dado que el operador tiene un valor fijo `50` y el operando tiene otro valor fijo  `2` se puede controlar que la multiplicación no creará un valor superior a lo que acepta el tipo de dato `byte`.

Por ejemplo esto funcionaría sin problemas, porque aquí no se reutiliza la variable `b`, sino que se crea una nueva, y se está operando sobre datos seguros:

```
    final byte b = 50;
    final int i=2;
    byte bMult = b * i;
```

---

#### Solución

Para evitar el error, como dice la especificación, hay que castear al tipo de dato cuando no uses expresiones constantes o no estés dentro de los casos especiales.

Así que dos soluciones son posibles:

#### Hacer el cast

```
b = (byte) (b * 2);
```

#### Usar expresiones constantes

```
final byte b = 50;
final int i=2;
byte bMult = b * i;
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.
Entiendo que los operandos se promueven automáticamente a int, cuando se evalúa la expresión, y ahora es de tipo int, que no se puede asignar a un byte sin el uso de una conversión.

Comment: @DiegoLoL realmente no ocurre una *Binary Numeric Promotion* como pensaba. El *quid* de la cuestión está explicado en el apartado *5.2. Assignment Contexts*  de la especificación (ya citado en la respuesta). Lo puede entender mejor leyendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48025287/5587982) y también [leyendo esto](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-narrowing-primitive-conversions-from-primitive-long-requires-explicit-casting/36). Por eso el contexto cambia radicalmente cuando las variables son declaradas como `final`.

Answer (score 3):

La operación por defecto es tratada como si fuesen enteros, debido a lo cual la perdida de datos (int usa mas de un byte) genera el error. La forma correcta de hacer la operación debería ser haciendo un cast de la operación:

```
 b = (byte)(b * 2);
```

Comment: Me parece una buena respuesta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un byte b y una constante 2, que es un int.

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), como son primitivas, hace un casting de int a byte y el error de compilación se da por la incompatibilidad entre tipos, pues de byte a int está permitido el *widening*, pero no en sentido contrario.

Comment: Ahora está mejor. Te doy positivo.

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer ese tipo de conversiones automaticas causan errores de compilacion ya que se intenta asignar un int (b * 2) a un byte (b).

[aqui](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/Automatic_Type_Promotion_in_Expressions.htm) y [aqui](http://leo.ugr.es/J2ME/CLDC/transjava/node3.html) puedes encontrar mas informacion referente a este prblema

la solucion podria ser algo asi:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    byte b = 50;
    b = (byte) (b * 2);

   System.out.println("b is " + b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class PromocionAutomaticaError {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte b = 50;
        b = b * (byte)2;
    }
}
```

El 2 te lo toma como int, parsealo como byte o también puedes hacer

```
class PromocionAutomaticaError {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte b = 50;
        byte multiplicador = 2;
        b = b * multiplicador;
    }
}
```